# Extract position of np.diagonal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array, and I would like to extract the diagonal using `np.diagonal`. More precisely, not the actual values, but the position of the values which `np.diagonal` would take.

```
size = 10
value = 1
offset = 1

array = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(size, size))

diagonal = np.diag(np.full(size,value))+np.diag(np.full(size-1, value),offset)+np.diag(np.full(size-1, value), -offset)   
diagonal = np.where(diagonal==0, np.nan, diagonal)
```

This works well if the offset is 1. If the offset is not 1, then the size is different, leading to this error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,10) (11,11)
```

How can I solve this? The resulting array `diagonal` should have the same size as the `array`.

Comment: Where is the error?  I'm guessing it's the attempt to add `np.diag`s, buy you  need to be clear about that., (to yourself as much as us).  This is a simple dimension difference which you should be able to track down.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to obtain here. Are you looking for the indices of the diagonal values in the array, or the indices of any value which appears in the diagonal of the array ? Could you provide an input/output exemple ?

Comment: It works with `np.diag(np.full(size-2, value), 2)`.  You have to adjust the `full` along with the `offset`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward fix seems to be subtracting the offset from the length of the array you're using to construct the diagonal.

```
diagonal = np.diag(np.full(size,value))+np.diag(np.full(size-offset, value),offset)+np.diag(np.full(size-offset, value), -offset)   
diagonal = np.where(diagonal==0, np.nan, diagonal)
```

Output with offset=2:

```
array([[ 1., nan,  1., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan,  1., nan,  1., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [ 1., nan,  1., nan,  1., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan,  1., nan,  1., nan,  1., nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan,  1., nan,  1., nan,  1., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan,  1., nan,  1., nan,  1., nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan,  1., nan,  1., nan,  1., nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  1., nan,  1., nan,  1.],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  1., nan,  1., nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  1., nan,  1.]])
```

If you really need the positions instead, you could change

```
diagonal = np.where(diagonal==0, np.nan, diagonal)
```

into

```
i, j = np.where(diagonal)
```

Edit:

Here's an alternative which creates all diagonals between the main diagonal and the offset diagonal.

```
size = 10
offset = 1
A = np.ones((size, size))
A[np.tril_indices(size, k=-(offset + 1))] = 0
A[np.triu_indices(size, k=(offset + 1))] = 0
A = np.where(A, 1, np.nan)
```

Comment: ok great! Now I would like to fill up the nan between the main diagonal and offset 2, or, in other words, include offset 1 in offset 2 (or if the offset = 3, offset 2 and 1). Thank you!

Comment: @Saraha See edit. I wanted to avoid looping over all of those offset diagonals, as that's slow, so I based this solution off of NumPy's [lower triangle/upper triangle](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html) functions. It starts with a full matrix and removes the upper and lower triangles.

Answer (score 3):

You could solve the problem using `np.indices`:

```
import numpy as np
size = 10
value = 1
offset = 2

x, y = np.indices((size, size))
np.where((abs(x - y) == offset) | (x == y), value, np.nan)

array([[ 1., nan,  1., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan,  1., nan,  1., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [ 1., nan,  1., nan,  1., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan,  1., nan,  1., nan,  1., nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan,  1., nan,  1., nan,  1., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan,  1., nan,  1., nan,  1., nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan,  1., nan,  1., nan,  1., nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  1., nan,  1., nan,  1.],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  1., nan,  1., nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  1., nan,  1.]])
```